# Find the quantum operation corresponding to a given unitary evolution and projective measurement

Tags: textbook-and-exercises, quantum-operation, nielsen-and-chuang, kraus-representation

I'm trying to (understand and) solve this problem from Nielsen and Chuang's *Quantum Computation and Quantum Information*.

[image]

I know the definition of Operation Elements: $\sum_{k} E_k \rho E_k^†$ with  $E_k = \langle e_k|U|e_0 \rangle$ where $e_k$ form the basis for the environment. But I'm not quite sure how this definition may be used to solve the problem above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, let the system be $\rho$, and the environment $|0\rangle \langle 0|$.

The given operation (which you can check is unitary, and incidentally happens to be the CNOT operation), is applied on $\rho \otimes |0\rangle \langle 0|$.

So, you have:
$$(P_0 \otimes I + P_1 \otimes X)(\rho \otimes |0\rangle \langle 0|)(P_0 \otimes I + P_1 \otimes X)$$

Now, you just expand it and multiply to get:
$$P_0 \rho P_0 \otimes |0\rangle \langle 0| + 
P_0 \rho P_1 \otimes |0\rangle \langle 1| +
P_1 \rho P_0 \otimes |1\rangle \langle 0| +
P_1 \rho P_1 \otimes |1\rangle \langle 1| $$

When you trace out the environment, you're left with:
$$P_0 \rho P_0 + P_1 \rho P_1$$

Thus the operator elements are $P_0$ and  $P_1$.

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot. So, in order to find operation elements, I need to use $U(\rho \otimes |0_E\rangle \langle0_E|) U^\dagger$.

Comment: @Bashir, yes, and then trace out the environment.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to the other answer (which is perfectly valid), we can use the formalism specified in the question. We're given a $U=P_0\otimes I+P_1\otimes X$. We know that the environment starts in state $|e_0\rangle=|0\rangle$. We need to establish an orthonormal basis for the environment, $|e_k\rangle$. In this case, it's straightforward as the environment is only two-dimensional:
$$
|e_0\rangle=|0\rangle\qquad |e_1\rangle=|1\rangle.
$$
Now we can apply the formula $E_k=(I\otimes \langle e_k|)U(I\otimes |e_0\rangle)$. Note that I've added in some identity elements to make it clearer that the environment basis only applies to the second subsystem. Now,
$$
U(I\otimes |e_0\rangle)=P_0\otimes|0\rangle+P_1\otimes|1\rangle,
$$
and so we have
$$
E_0=(I\otimes\langle 0|)(P_0\otimes|0\rangle+P_1\otimes|1\rangle)=P_0,
$$
and $E_1=P_1$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer using a different approach.